# Accessing self within decorator function within a Python class

Tags: python, scope, decorator

I've got a decorator function I'm applying to functions within a class. The decorator is supposed to do a check against an `_api` member variable. However, I get a `global name 'self' is not defined` error when I try to do this. What's the right way?

```
def requires_api(fn):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        if self._api is not None:
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return None
    return wrapped


@requires_api       
def do_something(self):
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reference to your instance is in your wrapper function's `*args` so the name `self` isn't avaialble. Use `args[0]`, or just rewrite it as:

```
def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...
```

Naturally, if you do this, your call through to the wrapped function should also include `self`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if self._api is not None:
```

to

```
if hasattr(args[0], '_api'):
```

`args[0]` has `self`.  [`hasattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hasattr) is the right way to check for an attribute.

If you try to access an attribute that does not exist, (if `self._api` does not exist) you will generate an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Thanks, you're correct, that was a mis-statement on my part- should be a comment though

Comment: @Yarin: What should be a comment?

Comment: @JoelCornett:  Thanks for the edit.  Found it just as I was preparing to write the same thing.  :)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: No problem. That's usually how it happens :)