# Python decorator within function, needs class within method?

Tags: python, class, decorator

Going off of [How can I define decorator method inside class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852138/how-can-i-define-decorator-method-inside-class) and [Accessing self within decorator function within a Python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064259/accessing-self-within-decorator-function-within-a-python-class), I have the following code:

```
class Custom():
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

    def renew(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                print('refreshing')
                self.refresh()
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    def refresh(self):
        self.var = 'refreshed'

    @renew
    def get_something(self):

        print(self.var)
        raise Exception

test = Custom('a')
test.get_something(test)
```

Which returns exactly what I want (pretend that the raise Exception is a expiration timeout, where var expires after some time, am just forcing an Exception here):

```
a
refreshing
refreshed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...
```

However, is there any way to not require the class instance `test` to be in the class method, namely `test.get_something(test)` -> `test.get_something()`? Or is this best practice? What is the best way to handle something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your renew decorator you are not passing instance parameter when calling the decorated function from wrapper. Wherever you want to call your func from wrapper, call it like this:

`func(self, *args, **kwargs)`

Once you correct the invocation call inside wrapper, you no longer need to pass class instance object when invoking your decorated function. So `test.get_something()` would work now.

Comment: thanks, just posting here (may want to update your answer if it is unclear to others) in each return, must be `return func(self, *args, **kwargs)`